# Display on the last line of specific group Crysal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92SIL.png) Please click the number one for the image... The wrong side is my actual report and  i want the format under the correct.

I need your guidance and expertise on this guys. I am doing an invoice report for the allowances of each employee.

**This is how my report looks like..**

Allowance for June 1,2014                            /**This is a Group Name:**/

1.Meal                          $8

2.Transpo                $8

Total                             $16                                       /**This is a Group Footer:**/

Allowance for June 2,2014                        /**This is a Group Name:**/

1.Meal                         $5

2.Transpo                $10

Total                           $15                                 /**This is a Group Footer:**/

**and now I want it to look like this.**

Allowance for June 1,2014                         /**This is a Group Name:**/

1.Meal                         $8

2.Transpo                 $8

Allowance for June2,2014                         /**This is a Group Name:**/

1.Meal                       $5

2.Transpo               $10

Total Allowance $31        /**One group Group footer**/

Crystal Report.

Answer (score 0):

- insert a group on employee; ensure that it is above/outside of the date group.
- move summary field from date group's footer to employee group's footer
- suppress the date group's footer

Comment: Hi Craig,Thank you so much for the reply. I tried your suggestion and it didn't works. I will Add an image on my reports.